# What's the payment for interviewee?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I mean, an online shopping mall company is trying to recruit some users for having an interview and research on their sales and their feeling.

In this situation, they want to give some money for them in return for their interview. What do you call this 'money'? Interview fee? Interview payment?

Answer (score 2):

The expression I'm familiar with for this is "**reimbursement for your time**". Specifically, I've heard this in the context of recruiting people for scientific research, which usually involves more than just an interview, but it's a sufficiently vague expression that it works here too.

Here are some examples:

> $100 reimbursement for your time to participate in a study testing the effectiveness of different forms of photography in improving memory recall.
>   <sub>[Centre for Healthy Brain Ageing UNSW](https://www.facebook.com/CHeBACentreforHealthyBrainAgeing/posts/100-reimbursement-for-your-time-to-participate-in-a-study-testing-the-effectiven/1101662573224221/)</sub>

> We will provide you with reimbursement for your time and parking will be at no cost.
>   <sub>[CHOP](https://www.chop.edu/clinical-trials?page=1)</sub>

> Reimbursement: You will not be charged for any of the study treatments and may be eligible for reimbursement for your time and effort.
>   <sub>[Diabetes Center](http://diabetes.ucsf.edu/clinical-trials-type-1-tilt-1)</sub>

Comment: I don't think "for your time" is needed.  Reimbursement works fine on its own. 
In your first example "Reimbursement for your participation".  In the second example "We will provide reimbursement and free parking".  In the third ".. may be eligible for reimbursement."